# querying Joomla! components from phpstorm does not work

Tags: joomla2.5, phpstorm

I'm trying to test some Joomla!'s output from phpstorm by using the inner "test RESTful web services" as known as "Rest client".

Basically the URL I would like to test asks for the component to load and task to perform. The loaded model by the controller reads the body of the POST request for performing some task.

To test it, I set my "Rest client" up: POST option, URL and body content are properly filled and then I run my request. Unfortunately, Joomla! seems not to read my URL parameters and because of this the home page is returned instead of loading the component, view and running the requested task.

Here is a snapshot of my settings:

[image]

Has anybody bumped into this issue? Any suggestion?

Comment: You are sending your POST data via `Request Body | Text`. Send it using `Request Parameters` list instead

Comment: It doesn't work anyway

Comment: I've discovered that if I don't set any request body (empty is selected), the controller and view are instantiated correctly

Answer (score 0):

I did it: I placed a new header item `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and it worked smoothly.

[image]